# Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL running on MAMP

Tags: macos, zend-framework, mamp

i updated to new version of MAMP 2.1 and I have got a problem with running project based on Zend Framework.

If I trying to run script, obtain error

```
Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL running on MAMP
```

Is any possibility, hot solve it?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Please show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

[T_SL](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) means <<
please check your source code